# All UITextField in a View

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8

In viewDidLoad I would scan all UITextField and a set addTarget with the code below. I have 3 UITextField but only 1 of that is found.

```
   for subview in self.view.subviews
   {
        println(subview)
       if (subview.isKindOfClass(UITextField))
       {
            var textField = subview as UITextField
                textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidReturn:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEndOnExit)

                textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidBeginEditing:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidBegin)
            }

    }
```

The view is very simple, built for exercise. 1 UIimageView, 3 UITextField, 1 button, 1 label. But the println(subview) display only

```
<UITextField: 0x7a739cf0; frame = (57 430; 290 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a739c90>>
<UIImageView: 0x7a742d70; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a742ef0>>
<_UILayoutGuide: 0x7a7430d0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a743270>>
<_UILayoutGuide: 0x7a743650; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a7436d0>>
```

The first UITextField is found and set, the others not. Why? Where am I wrong?

In other word. What is the right way to scan all the objects in a view?

Thanks

Comment: What you're doing is right. I would have to suggest that the runtime knows more than you do - your main view does _not_ contain three text fields and does _not_ contain a button or label. If it did, they'd be listed in the output. - You could experiment further by commenting out the whole if-clause and just concentrating on the `println` output, but I doubt that would make any difference (unless your app is crashing in the middle - is it?).

Comment: Thanks Matt. But I'm missing something. Did you mean that these objects are not in the main view but somewhere else? This is the whole project [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xmar5ioczqcjtm/TestText.zip?dl=0). Nothing complicated...

Comment: ...the code above is in ResponsiveTextFieldViewController.swift, if you have a little time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is merely that you are running your code too soon. Your code is in your view controller superclass's `viewDidLoad`. At that time, *its* view has loaded, but its subclass's view has not - and the subclass's view is where all the subviews are. So the result you are getting for your logging code, while surprising, is perfectly correct — *at the moment that the code runs*.

Just move your logging code into an implementation of `viewDidAppear:` or some other method that is called *after* the interface is completely ready, and you'll get the result you expect. I tested that with your project and it works fine.

Comment: OK. Now it's clear. I moved in viewDidAppear and the behavior is what expected. I will check to execute the code only once  Thank you so much Matt.

Comment: You are very welcome. Putting your project in dropbox was a very good idea! Once I downloaded it, I saw immediately what was happening.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple recursive method to find all textfields in some view,

```
func findAllTextFieldsInView(view: UIView) -> [UITextField]{
    var allTextFields = [UITextField]()

    for aView in view.subviews{
      if aView is UITextField{
        allTextFields.append(aView as UITextField)
      }
      let textFieldsInSubViews = findAllTextFieldsInView(aView as UIView)
      if textFieldsInSubViews.count > 0{
        allTextFields += textFieldsInSubViews
      }

    }
    return allTextFields
  }
```

Call this method and this will return all the textfield in the view and it returns array of all textfield,

```
findAllTextFieldsInView(self.view)
```

Adding action to the textfields is quite similar to the method above, I recurse all the subviews to find textfields and add target to it.

```
    func addControlEventToAllTextFieldsInView(view: UIView){
    for aView in view.subviews as [UIView]{
      if let textField = aView as? UITextField{
        textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidReturn:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEndOnExit)
        textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidBeginEditing:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidBegin)
      }
      addControlEventToAllTextFieldsInView(aView)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but nothing change. [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0qesjz60zvrj1rt/TestText2.zip?dl=0) the whole project. In ResponsiveTextFieldViewController.swift I added the code you suggest.

Comment: My code kept crashing for the method to find all textviews (in my case, textfield & textviews). So I modified it slightly and this seems to work fine for me:

Answer (score 0):

My code kept crashing for the method to find all textviews (in my case, textfield & textviews). So I modified it slightly and this seems to work fine for me:

```
func getAllTextInputViews(inView:UIView) -> [UITextInput] {

        var allTextFields = [UITextInput]()

        for aView in inView.subviews {
            if aView.isHidden {
                continue
            }
            else if aView is UITextField{
                allTextFields.append(aView as! UITextField)
            }
            else if aView is UITextView{
                allTextFields.append(aView as! UITextView)
            }else {
                let textFieldsInSubViews = getAllTextInputViews(inView:aView as UIView)
                if textFieldsInSubViews.count > 0{
                    allTextFields += textFieldsInSubViews
                }
            }
        }
        return allTextFields
    }
```