# Why is my ViewControllers view.subviews count incorrect?

Tags: xcode, swift, viewcontroller, subviews

My ViewController contains

- a label
- a button
- 4 imageviews
- 2 textfields

Why is `self.view.subviews` only returning an array with 2 elements?

Here is a screenshot of my Xcode project:

[image: Screenshot]

**Edit**
I made a new Viewcontroller containing a switch and a label.

my viewDidLoad() code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for v in self.view.subviews{
        println(v)
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

println(v) outputs 2 UILayoutGuide objects:

```
    <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7c94c450; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c94b5c0>>  <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7c94c850; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c94b1a0>>
```

(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription] output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vbBl.png
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vbBl.png]

Comment: `println(v)` would let you see which two views are present.

Comment: Or run app through the debugger, press "pause" button and at `(lldb)` prompt type `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`, and see entire view hierarchy.

Comment: By the way, if you're trying to match up views in the hierarchy with what you added in IB, give the views unique `tag` numbers in IB, and that tag number is shown in the view hierarchy recursiveDescription.

Comment: The answer given and deleted by Ashok was right; you are counting _too soon_. Do your count _later_ than `viewDidLoad` - for example, in `viewDidAppear:`. Compare my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26569059/341994

Comment: The d object is an outlet for the ViewControllers View object. I used it before to test some things but removed the code, so the outlet is redundant

Comment: And the Latin for "without a name" is "Sine Nomine", not "Sine Nomen". Bad Latin is never appreciated on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks Ashoks answer helped me, dont know why he removed it.
I'm just curious because I have a sample project where counting the subviews inside viewDidLoad does work.

Answer (score 1):

Your subviews haven't been loaded yet. You should run this code in `awakeFromNib`, or in any of the methods called later, like `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. From the docs:

> An `awakeFromNib` message is sent […] after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives an `awakeFromNib` message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet instance variables set.

And some more details:

> When you create a view controller in a storyboard, the attributes you configure in Interface Builder are stored in an archive. Later, when the view controller is instantiated, this archive is loaded into memory and processed. […] After the objects in the archive are loaded, iOS calls the `awakeFromNib` method on any objects that implement such a method. You use this method to perform any configuration steps that require other objects to already be instantiated.